Text Spacing Inconsistency Between Emulator and Real Device
I'm encountering a difference in text spacing between the design view in my emulator and the actual app running on a real device. The text appears to have more spacing between characters and lines in the emulator compared to the device (screenshots attached).
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(25.dp).fillMaxSize(),
    text = "Park Street, San jose, California, United States ark Street, San jose, California, United States Park Street, San jose, California, United States ark Street, San jose, California, United States Park Street, San jose, California, United States ark Street, San jose, California, United States ",
    fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
    fontSize = 11.sp,
    color = DarkBlue1,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
)

Also found out that if we run it as a preview it works in emulator but not as a full app run
Left: Emulator (Pixel 6a API 34)
Right: Real device



Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] that we can use to reproduce this behavior.

Updated the question as per your instructions

I cannot reproduce your emulator screenshot. When I use the same emulator or a preview they both look the same as your right screenshot. I'm not sure where the extra line spacing is coming from in your left screenshot; maybe some accessibility setting in the emulator?

I found the solution.
The issue was due to includeFontPadding parameter in style tag. Update code as below to resolve it. Using same textview as the question
Text(
     modifier = Modifier.padding(25.dp).fillMaxSize(),
     text = "Park Street, San jose, California, United States ark Street, San      jose, California, United States Park Street, San jose, California, United States      ark Street, San jose, California, United States Park Street, San jose, California,      United States ark Street, San jose, California, United States ",
     fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
     fontSize = 11.sp,
     color = DarkBlue1,
     overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,

     platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle( includeFontPadding = false )

 )

You can also use the same in compose material theme so it applies to whole app and you dont have to update in every Text instance like below.
val fontStyle = TextStyle(
    platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
        includeFontPadding = false
    )
)

MaterialTheme(
    colorScheme = colorScheme,
    typography = Typography(
        displayLarge = fontStyle,
        displayMedium = fontStyle,
        displaySmall = fontStyle,
        headlineLarge = fontStyle,
        headlineMedium = fontStyle,
        headlineSmall = fontStyle,
        titleLarge = fontStyle,
        titleMedium = fontStyle,
        titleSmall = fontStyle,
        bodyLarge = fontStyle,
        bodyMedium = fontStyle,
        bodySmall = fontStyle,
        labelLarge = fontStyle,
        labelMedium = fontStyle,
        labelSmall = fontStyle,
    ),
    content = content
)

Answering my own question. Bruh..
